# rsync-path: No such file or directory when used with subprocess.Popen

Tags: rsync, python

I use `rsync` to deploy code from one server to another. On a staging directory I build the application by placing all files (e.g. php scripts) like they should appear on the remote application server (the files are owned by me). After that I use rsync (with a python deployment wrapper tool) to synchronize the new file structure with the remote one.

The call in python looks like:

```
rsync = ['/usr/bin/rsync', '-avP', '--rsync-path="sudo -u www-data -g www-data /usr/bin/rsync"', stage_dir, getpass.getuser() + '@' + server + ':/data/application'] + DEFAULT_RSYNC_ARGS
start = time.time()
logger.debug('Running rsync command: `%s`', ' '.join(rsync))
p = subprocess.Popen(rsync, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()

if stdout:
    logger.debug(stdout)
if stderr:
    logger.error(stderr)
```

The `DEFAULT_RSYNC_ARGS` are defined as:

```
DEFAULT_RSYNC_ARGS = [
    '--exclude=**/.svn/lock',
    '--exclude=**/mw-config/private',
    '--exclude=**/localisationCache',
    '--exclude=**/main/mw-config',
    '--exclude=**/main/sitemap',
    '--exclude=**./services',
    '--exclude=**/.git',
    '--no-perms',
    '--archive',
    '--delete-delay',
    '--delay-updates',
    '--compress',
    '--delete',
]
```

However, if I run the script, I get the following error message:

```
21:59:51 rsync: -avP--rsync-path="sudo -u www-data -g www-data /usr/bin/rsync": unknown option
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1572) [client=3.1.0]
```

However, if I run the command from the log file:

```
/usr/bin/rsync -aqP --rsync-path='sudo -u www-data -g www-data /usr/bin/rsync' /data/deployment/staging/ user@serverhost:/data/application --exclude=**/.svn/lock --exclude=**/mw-config/private --exclude=**/localisationCache --exclude=**/main/mw-config --exclude=**/main/sitemap --exclude=**./services --exclude=**/.git --no-perms --archive --delete-delay --delay-updates --compress --delete
```

anything works fine. Does someone has a hint, why it doesn't work as expected when using python?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30010939/python-subprocess-popen-error-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: Hmm, I could try this, however, it's working fine, if I don't pass the rsync-path parameter (however, the files at the remote server will be owned by me, as I logged into the server, but instead I want them to be owned by www-data without chown).